# (Python Selenium) Is there a way to read the html elements above a button before clicking a button?

Tags: python, html, selenium

[html inspect image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vZvZ.png)

```
<td class="hidden-sm-down">Extra Time</td>
<td class="hidden-sm-down">2020-08-08T15:00</td>
<td class="hidden-sm-down">2020-08-08T19:00</td>
<td>Approved</td>
<td class="hidden-sm-down">  
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data 
      target="#cancelRequestModal" data-toggle="modal" type="button">                                     
      Cancel
```

The format of the website is in the image above but will be repeated for different dates/times; I was wondering if there was a way to check the time (like 15:00 and 19:00) before clicking the "Cancel" button.  The way I was doing it before was to put all the buttons into a list and click the one with index 9, however that does not work if all there was a missing shift and the previous index 9 is now index 8 (a shift before index 9 was removed so everything above is shifted down).

One was I was thinking was to read for time and then click the first clickable button, however, I do not know how to do this or if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best way to read the HTML element above a button is to use 'Xpath'. `Xpath` will give you functionality/ability to navigate back and forth.

By using the below `XPath` you can extract the texts inside `<td>`. Moreover, you can repeat the same by collecting it into the list.

for 1st `<td>` with time you can use the below `xpath` -
`//button[contains(text(),"Cancel")]/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td[text()='Extra Time']/following-sibling::td[1]`

for 2nd `<td>` with time you can use the below `xpath` -
`//button[contains(text(),"Cancel")]/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td[text()='Extra Time']/following-sibling::td[2]`

you can extract text by using `.text` property.

I'm finding the timing in relation to your button which consists of **'Cancel'** text. To extract the exact time you can use the `substring()` method.

Comment: My new code is
`time=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Cancel')]/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td[text()='Extra Time']/following-sibling::td[1]")`


however whenever I do `time[0].click()`, it does not seem to work.  The element the variable seems to refer to is now the time and not the button itself, unlike when I do 

`Time=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Cancel')]")`

and `Time[1].click()` and the button is pressed

@Swaroop

Comment: Never mind, it works for me.  I ended up creating 2 different variables `Time` (the actual 'Cancel' button) to be indexed to the corresponding correct `time` (the variable for the time check)